# Let $E$ be normed space. Show that the sets $E \setminus \{0\}$ and $A=\{x \in E \mid 1 < |x|< 2 \}$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $E$ be normed space. Show that the sets $E \setminus \{0\}$ and $A=\{x \in E \mid 1 < |x|< 2 \}$ are homeomorphic.

I’m trying to learn about homeomorphisms and not entirely sure how to approach these problems. I need to find a map $\varphi:E \setminus \{0\} \to A$ thats continuous bijection with continuous inverse. If I would consider $E = \mathbb{R}^2$, then A would be the strips between $(-2,-1)$ and $(1,2)$. How does one approach these problems? Should I try to visualize this first or how should I start thinking about candidates for $\varphi$?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should start with the simplest $E=\mathbb{R}$ case. Can you find a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\to (-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$? Such homeomorphism can be constructed from a homeomorphism $g:(0,\infty)\to(1,2)$ by taking $-g$ on the negative part. Finally $g$ can be constructed from some trigonometric functions, which I leave as an exercise.

For general $E$ this becomes quite easy now. Because we can simply rescale each vector via our $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\to (-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$ homeomorphism. I.e.

$$F:E\backslash\{0\}\to A$$
$$F(v)=f(\lVert v\rVert)\cdot \frac{v}{\lVert v\rVert}$$

which simply says "take vector $v$ and change its norm from $\lVert v\rVert$ to $f(\lVert v\rVert)$". This "change norm" is done by first normalizing $v$ via $\frac{v}{\lVert v\rVert}$ and then scaling via multiplication by $f(\lVert v\rVert)$. I leave as an exercise that it is continuous.

You can also check (via tedious calculation) that the explicit inverse of $F$ is

$$G:A\to E\backslash\{0\}$$
$$G(v)= f^{-1}(\lVert v\rVert)\cdot\frac{v}{\lVert v\rVert}$$

which is automatically continuous by previous argument.

Comment: If I understood this correctly we don't actually have an explicit function for $f$? We just state that it's a map from the reals excluding zero to the union and then define a new map on the general norm space to use $f$ to "scale" all it's point so that it fits our needs?

Comment: @DanielLi the $f$ function I'm using in the general case it the one we've constructed in the special $E=\mathbb{R}$ case. But yes, we only care about its properties (homeomorphism), not concrete formula. And yes, we use it to construct the capital $F$ homeomorphism.